# How can I parse incoming JSON string where the model I'm deserializing to contains JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class ClientRow
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public DateTime EditedOn { get; set; }
}
```

The Data property contains JSON.

When the UI updates one of these rows and submits it it comes to my controller action as a single string in JSON format.  For example:

```
{
    Id: <guid>,
    Product: "Generic Widget",
    Price: 25.99,
    Quantity: 25,
    EditedOn: 12/13/2015
}
```

Note: `Id` and `EditedOn` will always be included but there can be any number of other fields in this JSON. I need to somehow deserialize the JSON into the model where the fields that are not part of the model are a JSON object store in `Data`.

```
var row = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientRow>(incoming);
```

This gets me an object populated with `Id` and `EditedOn` but of course the `Data` is not populated.  How can I take ALL the remaining fields and store that JSON in `Data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to not deserialize to your `ClientRow` object directly. Instead, we want to deserialize to an `ExpandoObject` which allows us to dynamically add properties at runtime.

```
string json = "{Id: \"2db55af1-109c-46aa-ba36-e61ae6e5a6e1\", Product: \"Generic Widget\", Price: 25.99, Quantity: 25, EditedOn: \"12/13/2015\"}";  
dynamic deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, new ExpandoObjectConverter());

ClientRow cr = new ClientRow
{
    Id = new Guid(deserialized.Id),
    EditedOn = DateTime.ParseExact(deserialized.EditedOn, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
};

IDictionary<string, object> propertyValues = (IDictionary<string, object>)deserialized;
foreach (var property in propertyValues)
{
    if (!(property.Key.Equals("Id") || property.Key.Equals("EditedOn")))
    {
        cr.Data += property.Value.ToString() + " ";
    }
}

// cr now contains our final deserialized result
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cr));
```

Once we have our `ExpandoObject`, we can manually map the two properties, `Id` and `EditedOn`, that we know should always be the same.

Since `ExpandoObjects` implement `IDictionary`, we can iterate through the key-value pairs of properties. For every property that we find that is not `Id` or `EditedOn` that we have already mapped, we append its string representation to the data property.

Comment: I'd never even heard of this ExpandoObject before.  In fact, I typed it as "ExpandedObject" several times and was confounded as to why Intellisense was having such an issue with it. :)  Thanks.